# Deleting Rows Based on Cell Value Criteria in a Column, for All Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

For every worksheet in my workbook (about 30 tabs), I am trying to delete all rows that have the string value of "NA" in `Column F`.

```
' Setting Display Alerts OFF
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Declare ws as a worksheet object variable.
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

' Initiate Loop
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set rng = ws.Range("A16:F" & Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row) 
        With rng
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="NA"                                           
            'Make sure it aligns with the lettered column defined above
            rng.Resize(rng.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete 
            .AutoFilter
        End With
Next ws

' Toggling Display Alerts ON
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

However, this only seems to work for the very first sheet. All other subsequent sheets do not have their respective rows removed. Additionally, the macro runs without any errors.

I believe my loop to apply this deletion process is not being applied to the other sheets. What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Set rng = ws.Range("A16:F" & ws.Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)` - you are missing a `ws`.

Comment: A big tell is when something is not fully qualified in this case it is `Cells`. Using `With/End With ` and then *always* having a "dot" in front of all objects referring to that object helps.

Comment: I feel silly for missing that reference, I figured the parent loop in which the sheet was being referenced would be enough. Thank you all for your feedback!